# Regex and Javascript pattern build

Tags: javascript, regex

I just really need help with building a regex of this pattern XXX@XXX.XXX

```
Starts with at least 3 char not @
then @ (only one)
at least 3 char that are not . or @
and than one .
than 3 char that are not . or @
```

This is what I played with
but it doesnt work

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]{3,})\.@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]{3,*})\.[a-zA-Z]{3,*}$/
```

Comment: What characters are legal? Are you trying to match an email address? You might try searching first, as there are hundreds of questions like this.

Comment: and if that's for validating email addresses, I can 99% guarantee that none of the answers are correct

Comment: At least keep your bad regex consistent! You put `{3,}` which is correct, but then later you put `{3,*}` twice...

Comment: How does it not work?  The regular expression you described is `/[^@]{3,}@[^@.]{3,}\.[^@.]{3}/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[^@]{3,}@[^@\.]{3,}\.[^@\.]{3}$
```

This is the regex you're looking for. But if you want to validate an e-mail address don't use this regex.

Comment: This is the regex he described, but I think it is very unlikely it is the one he is looking for.

Comment: true ;-) Validating e-mail with this regex is not proper

Comment: @AdamWolski, You are missing the `^...$`, otherwise we could have `/[^@]{3,}@[^@\.]{3,}\.[^@\.]{3}/.test('@invalid@test.com'); //true`

Comment: According to his description, this can be valid. Note, that he didn't say that it should validate an e-mail address.

Comment: But, according to his attempt (he used ^ and $) you're right ;)

Comment: @AdamWolski, FYI: you don't need to escape `.` when it is in a set.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 /\b[^@]{3,}@[^.@]{3,}\.[^.@]{3}\b/
```

it should work. The `\b` means a token boundary.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([^@]{3,})@([^.@]{3,})\.([^.@]{})$/
```

First block matches atleast 3 characters that are not @
Second is one @
Third is atleast 3 characters that are not . or @
Fourth is a .
Fifth is 3 characters that are not . or @